# Fetch data from three tables two tables have one same column

Tags: php, mysqli

I have three tables a,b,c

```
table a

sender   status     type
name1    approved    one
name1    approved    one
name1    approved    two
name2    pending     one



table b

sender    p_id
name1     001
name2     003
name1     005
name2     005
name1     003


table c

p_id     p_name     st
001      p1         complete
002      p2         current
003      p3         current
005      p4         current
```

I want my output like this

```
 sender    status    type   p_id    p_name   st
name1      approved   one   005      p4      current
name1      approved   one   003      p3      current
name1      approved   two
name2      approved   two   003      p3      current
name2                       005      p4      current
```

all senders who have status approved in table a and with their p_id status   current in table c using table b;

Comment: You don't appear to have tried anything, or even read the manual...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by running the following query:

```
SELECT a.sender,a.status,a.type,c.p_id,c.p_name,c.st 
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.sender=b.sender 
INNER JOIN c ON b.p_id = c.p_id
WHERE a.status='approved' AND c.st='current';
```